# Is there any program that will render all segments of non-silence from an mp3 file into a separate file?

Tags: audio, mp3, mount, audacity

There is an mp3 file. It consists of different songs, between which there is silence. I need to make each song from this file become a separate file. It is not possible to render them manually because the main mp3 file is longer than 15 hours.
Is there any program or some script that will render all non-silence segments (that is, where the volume is > 0) into a separate file?
P.S. (Let this script pronominate the resulting files one by one, and then I will listen to each file and give it the correct name.)

[Visual representation of what I need to do:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX4Fb.png)